# How can I vertically align text and button to the center of screen in React Native using Tailwind?

Tags: react-native, tailwind-css

Working with Tailwind and react native for the first time. I need help with the why styling and alignment is not working for this started project.

Please check the screenshot - The text and button are supposed to be in the middle of the screen.

[App simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyiWu.png)

```
import React from "react";
import { Button, Text, StyleSheet, View, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import { useTailwind } from 'tailwind-rn';


export default function App() {
  const tw = useTailwind();

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={tw('h-full')}>

        <View style={tw("flex-1 items-center justify-center")}>
          <Text style={tw('text-blue-600')}> asf !! </Text>
          <Button title="Click me" />
        </View>
        
    </SafeAreaView>

  );
}
```

Trying to align button and text to the middle of the screen